# Anyone have best practices for promoting workflow and list form changes between dev and prod?

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, custom-form, list-form

I'm pretty new to the SharePoint world and am developing a series of custom changes to existing list forms and a set of SharePoint 2010 workflows (SharePoint 2013 Designer) in our organization's on-prem SharePoint 2019 development farm.

I see a lot of work to manually implement the changes in the production farm, not to mention an increased risk of errors. Copying the form .aspx files does not appear to be an option since web part IDs are different between the environments.

Does anyone have any suggestions or best practices for implementing/promoting custom forms and workflow changes from a development farm and a production farm? The farms are completely separate - different servers, accounts, etc.

Thank you.